# Could I get a visa for Australia as a self-taught software developer in 2024?

Tags: visa, australia

I'd like to know if is possible to get a visa for Australia as a 34 years old self-taught software developer. I don't have a degree.

Instead, I have 11 years of experience until now, I've worked as Senior Software Engineer for companies from EEUU (India development team), and Tel Aviv, Israel; remotely from Chile. My english level is around B2 upper intermediate or so (working on those companies).

Do I have any chances to get a visa? I've heard about the Skilled VISA and it seems like there are some exceptions for IT careers about having degree and the years of experience that are considered for applying.

What plan would you recommend for me to emigrate to Australia based on my context?

Any advice is welcome. I'm new in this topic.

Thank you! and happy new year!

Comment: It's possible but this is too broad. Do a bit of research and come back with more specific questions.